# Are there online resources from which I can study ancient Umbrian?

Tags: historical-linguistics, resource-request, online-resources, ancient, italic

Unfortunately I can not find a substantial resource that can help me in the study of ancient Umbrian. I have tried to search up on the Web, however the only resources I had found were about lexicon.
If kindly some expert on the subject knows some book on Umbrian grammar, could he/she let me know? Please.

Comment: Start with [the Bronze Tablets of Iguvium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iguvine_Tablets) and look in the sources there. You'll probly hafta use a university library eventually; Umbrian is not popular on the Web.

Comment: [Buck's 1904 grammar of Oscan and Umbrian](https://archive.org/details/grammarofoscanum00buckuoft)  appears to be available for download. Whether there's anything more recent I don't know.,

Comment: Online probably not but I recommend Rix, Helmut 1993. *Oskisch-Umbrisch: Texte Und Grammatik*. Wiesbaden: Reichert. It's in German though.